# Problema con caracteres especiales obtenidos de Webservice

Tags: php, html, webservice, curl

Tengo el siguiente problema, ya coloqué los encabezados meta charset UTF-8 en mi pagina web para visualizar los caracteres especiales, al ver la pagina en mi PC local se ve bien, sin embargo, los acentos los convierte a Mayuscula cuando deberia ser Minuscula, y en el servidor los caracteres especiales simplemente no se ven, aparece un simbolo extraño.

Para mostrar los productos en la pagina web estoy consumiendo un Webservice mediante CURL en PHP (Estos son los datos con los que tengo problemas con los caracteres especiales), el resto del texto que no proviene del Webservice si se visualiza bien incluyendo los caracteres especiales, lo que me lleva a pensar que el problema viene del Webservice (El cual tambien programé yo).

¿Debo agregar algo a la pagina web?
¿Debo modificar algo en el Webservice?

**Esta es una Captura de Pantalla:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuáles cabeceras envía tu webservice?

Comment: @Sal Tengo estas 2:  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Hay que revisar varias puntos, es muy recomendable que revises primero [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-carácter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base/59510#59510).